# How I can launch Datalab via Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I am able to create the datalab instance via Cloudshell with `datalab create datalab-instance-name` shell command but unable to find a way to create it via GCP console.

Is there any specific reason for not allowing to create datalab via GCP console?

Comment: There's no good reason to include it in the console UI in my opinion, since Datalab is just a GCE VM running a custom image. Launching it using cloudshell is a one liner, is there any specific use case that this doesn't satisfy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reviewed the [Cloud Datalab Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs) and I could confirmed that the only way to create a datalab instance is via the `datalab create` command. This is the only available option regardless the location/region where the datalab instance is being generated.

In case this feature doesn't cover your current needs, you can use the **Send Feedback** button, located at the lower left and upper right corners of the [service public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs), as well as use the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) tool in order to [raise a Datalab feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187138&template=1101061) and notify to Google about this desired functionality.